# Composite meta types choice field

Tags: c1-cms

Is it possible to render a meta type field as a choice field?

For example, I'd like editors to choose an option from a list of available items. There is no control like this, but I seem to be able to do this with a Data Reference type, but I don't know where I need to add the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Selector](http://users.composite.net/Superuser/Data/A-Guide-to-Creating-Datatypes/Widgets#_Toc251670522) widget.

- When editing your field, go to the "advanced" tab.
- Click on the button to change the widget type, which currently contains "TextBox".
- Delete the TextBox widget.
- Add a new widget, the Composite.Widgets.Selector.
- Specify a function to return the options.